# Call Javascript from a .js file on Window resize

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

How can I call a Javascript from a local .js file when the window is resized?

Here is the code in my .js file, which may or may not work because I can't figure out how to call it, but that's besides the point...

```
function sizeGutter()
{
    var p = document.getElementById("MIIHomeBtn");
    var offset = p.offsetTop + p.offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("gutterDiv").style.top = offset + "px";
    document.getElementById("gutterDiv").style.height = document.getElementById("gutterDiv").offsetHeight - offset + "px";
}
```

And then I want to put
`window.onresize = sizeGutter;` into my html, but I'm not really sure how, or if that is even the right approach.

Please help.

Comment: <body onload="window.onresize = sizeGutter;">

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: @John writing it in attribute is a bad idea.

Comment: just write window.onresize = function1 and etc. or use jquery.

Comment: Where would I write window.onresize = myFunction if not in the attribute?

Comment: That was my entire question....

Comment: Yes, I read that.  Thus my question. I don't know where to place it to get it to work.  I'm missing something really simple here...

Comment: Simply create a `<script>` tag and put your code inside it.

Comment: So your question is basically "how do I use javascript?" or "how do I add javascript to my page?" If so, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup